# Is it possible to get a list of all mapped entities from NHibernate IStatelessSession or ISession?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to write a test for my NHibernate mappings that will automatically pick up and test any new mappings that get added.

At the moment I have a test that opens a session to a known test database then attempts to load the first entity of each type and asserts that it is not null.

This all works fine but it means that every time I add a new entity mapping, I need to remember to update the test.

So, what I want to do is to inspect the mappings and try to load one of each of the mapped entities, but the NHibernate Configuration object that the sessionfactory is built from is not visible to my test so I was wondering if there is a way to access a list of mapped entities from the session or do I need to expose the original Configuration instead?

Comment: Nikolay's answer pointed me in the right direction although I am using an IStatelessSession so I need to call `session.GetSessionImplementation().Factory.GetAllClassMetadata()` to get the metadata.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get SessionFactory from Session and SessionFactory has method GetAllClassMetadata() which returns list of IClassMetadata. And from IClassMetadata you can get MappedClass (GetMappedClass())

But you will need some extra work to get subclasses. This code can help:

```
var metaData = this.session.SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(baseClass);
if (metaData != null && metaData.HasSubclasses)
{
    foreach (string entityName in ((NHibernate.Persister.Entity.IEntityPersister)metaData).EntityMetamodel.SubclassEntityNames)
    {
        var metadata = this.session.SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(entityName);
        result.Add(metadata.GetMappedClass(EntityMode.Poco));
    }
}
```

Comment: The GetAllClassMetadata() was just the method that I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I expose the configuration object and do a mapping that queries all of my entities like this.  It will output all errors from each of my mappings.:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void AllNHibernateMappingsAreOkay()
{
    bool failed = false;
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

    using (ISession session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession())
    {
        foreach (var s in SessionFactory.GetConfig().ClassMappings)
        {
            try
            {
                SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().CreateQuery(string.Format("from {0} e", s.MappedClass.Name))
                    .SetFirstResult(0).SetMaxResults(50).List();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                failed = true;
                log.ErrorFormat("\r\n\r\n {0} \r\n {1} \r\n\r\n", ex.Message, ex.InnerException.Message);   
            }
        }
    }

    Assert.IsFalse(failed, "One or more mappings have errors in them.  Please refer to output or logs.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to avoid having to expose the Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

if you have only one row per entity then you could issue `session.QueryOver<object>().List();`